# Is a 32-bit ASP.NET app running on 64-bit Windows LARGEADDRESSAWARE

Tags: asp.net, 32bit-64bit

I have an existing 32-bit ASP.NET application that used 32-bit unmanaged DLLs.

If I run this on a 64-bit OS, will it automatically be LARGEADDRESSAWARE (i.e. have access to the full 4GB of virtual memory)?

If not, what can I do to make it LARGEADDRESSAWARE?

Googling turned up [this question](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/332754-run-asp-net-application-largeaddressaware), but it lacks the answer to the above question.

**EDIT**

[This blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/dougste/archive/2006/03/14/551479.aspx) suggests that the ASP.NET 1.1 worker process is LARGEADDRESSAWARE, but is silent about ASP.NET 2.0:

> If a system is booted with the /3Gb
>   switch in boot.ini (only supported on
>   Enterprise and Data Center editions of
>   Windows 2000, and all versions of
>   Windows XP and Windows Server 2003) a
>   process that is linked with the
>   /LARGEADDRESSAWARE switch can "see"
>   3Gb. Aspnet_wp.exe is linked in that
>   way in version 1.1 and can take
>   advantage of that.

**EDIT 2**

[This is another blog](http://bilbroblog.com/wow64/hidden-secrets-of-w0w64-ndash-large-address-space/)  that suggests that 32-bit ASP.NET apps are LARGEADDRESSAWARE, but doesn't mention the ASP.NET version:

> We found the components that were
>   hosted by the ASP.NET framework were
>   taking advantage of the > 2 gig memory
>   space

I must say I'm amazed at the lack of authoritative published information on this subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get access to a server running Windows 2003 SP2, and the answer appears to be yes, 32-bit ASP.NET applications are LARGEADDRESSAWARE, and have access to the full 4GB of virtual memory.

I established this by:

- examining w3wp.exe (the 32-bit IIS worker process) using "dumpbin /headers".  This shows that the LARGEADDRESSAWARE bit is set.
- running a 32-bit ASP.NET application that attempts to allocate over 2GB of virtual memory: this was successful.

I assume the result would be the same for Windows 2008 / IIS7, but haven't tested it.

Answer (score -1):

No it will not.   To make it large address aware, you have to run the IIS as a 64-bit application (not running using WOW).  This means that your 32-bit unmanaged dlls will have to be replaced with the 64-bit versions of them.

Normally, asp.net will convert to a 64-bit application when selecting the compiler option to target any platform (which is the default).  The problem with the 32-bit app you have is that there are unmanaged 32-bit dlls.  These cannot run in a 64-bit application.  This means that you have to run your ASP.NET application as a 32-bit application which means that you have to install the 32-bit version of IIS on your 64-bit server.  The only way to avoid this is to replace the 32-bit unmanaged dlls with ones which are designed to run in a 64-bit environment.  A 32-bit application can't use all of the memory on 64-bit server, so your application won't be able to "see" the additional memory.

ASP.NET apps will recompile themselves (providing the target any environment option is set at compile time) in a 64-bit environment, so they aren't 32-bit apps anymore.

Comment: "No it will not." - Thanks.  Any references for this?  And is it possible to change this?

Comment: I'm still looking for an article.

Comment: "To make it large address aware, you have to run the IIS as a 64-bit application" - what do you mean by this?  If it's a 64-bit app, it won't be running on WOW64 and LARGEADDRESSAWARE is not relevant.